# How to reduce margins in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress and having a hard time making it do what I want.  I'm using the twenty-seventeen theme and it puts too much vertical space around the home page content.  You can see what I mean here: [www.tekknow.net](http://www.tekknow.net)

If I press F12 in the chrome browser and look at the elements containing the content, it goes from outer to inner tags like this:

> 1. class = "site-content-contain"
> 2. id="content" class = "site-content"
> 3. id="primary" class = "content-area"
> 4. id="main" class = "site-main"
> 5. id="post-30" class = "twentyseventeen-panel post-30 page type-page status-publish hentry"
> 6. class="panel-content"
> 7. class="wrap"

The inner most one is #7 so I've put that into the *customizing additional css* section like this:

```
.wrap {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

When I float my cursor over the wrap class in the chrome elements, I still see a lot of green padding above the text "HOME PAGE", yet I have set padding-top to 0.  I've also verified that there is 0 border, margin, and padding in items 1-6.  Suggestions?

Comment: I would start by creating a child theme of the twenty-seventeen theme, and just using your own CSS file to overwrite those specific styles.

Comment: My understanding of the customizing additional css section is that is exactly what it does.  Any css in that section is supposed to override the theme css.  Do you know of cases where that is not true?

Comment: If that's all you want to do, you can certainly use that section - especially if it is just CSS. As you dig further into WP, you may want to go the route of child theme, but for now, use that additional css section - I forget that's available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to remove the padding from the top then you will need to edit these `CSS` rules:

```
.panel-content .wrap {
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 1.75em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 30em)
.panel-content .wrap {
    padding-bottom: 2em;
    padding-top: 3.5em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 48em)
.panel-content .wrap {
    padding-bottom: 4.5em;
    padding-top: 6em;
}
```

You can also see that there is different styling for different screen sizes.

You could eventually add `!important` to:

```
.wrap {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The !important addition worked.  I forgot about that and why/when it is needed.  Will research it.  Thank you!

Comment: Although it worked for the padding-top, it did not work for the margin.  if I do "margin: 0px !important" in the .wrap class, nothing happens.  There remains a large amount of orange margin causing the text to wrap too soon.  Wordpress is not worth the hassle in my opinion.  Better to do it the old fashioned way to save yourself a lot of time and frustration.

Comment: The orange space that you might be seeing comes from here: `@media screen and (min-width: 30em) .page-one-column .panel-content .wrap`. In this case it is not a margin but `max-width: 740px;`. You could either remove that `CSS` rule or set `max-width: 100%`. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I´ll suggest you to write a new CSS file and save it under style.css
Presently, the .wrap class has a style of

padding-bottom: 4.5em;
padding-top: 6em;

which is saved under http://tekknow.net/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css?ver=20190507

So, just write a new CSS file or edit the .wrap class files from there.

All the best!

Comment: Never edit the theme files directly. This is bad advice.